# Environment variable named 3P is not detected by visual studio. Is it because it is impossible?

Tags: visual-studio, environment-variables

I was trying to use an environment variable named **3P** to keep keep the third party libraries, so that the issue with relative paths in different machines doesn't cause any build failures, if they define this environment variable correctly.

But the name **3P** is not detected by my Visual Studio 2013 and 2017. I have tried to compile it through command line. I have tried it in a different machine. I have even tried turning it on and off again. Is possible to use an environment variable in visual studio with a name starting in a digit?

**Environment variables visible in Visual Studio 2013 (3P is not visible)**

[image: Environment variables visible in Visual Studio 2013 (3P is not visible)]

**Environment variables (3P is *D:\GitStorage\3P*)**

[image: Environment variables (3P is *D:\GitStorage\3P*)]

Comment: @kenlukas Sorrry, I didn't know that your name will go if I edit again :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Three_P` instead or anything that doesn't start with a digit, because operating systems and programming stacks are weird about that.

For example, Bash won't even let you shoot yourself in the foot:

```
$ export 3P=true
-bash: export: `3P=true': not a valid identifier
$ export ThreeP=true
$
```

Comment: This has indeed crossed my mind. But there is a consistent practice of naming most of the third party things 3P in my organization. So it would be nice if it is possible to name it so. Is it an OS issue though?

Comment: Mostly because the compiler could confuse it with a number literal (if you can start with a digit, what's stopping you from naming your variable `33` then?). That's the case for C# with Roslyn at least. I believe other programming stacks have the same behavior. It's a good moment to change that naming practice in your organization.